# Spring boot - Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new on spring-boot.
I have an error when I start my spring-boot application on the port 8080. I get
**Whitelabel Error Page**.

I have created a very simple html page in **/src/main/resources/templates/**.

Here is my pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyBanQ</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MyBanQ</name>
    <description>compta Project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the controller of my application

```
public class BanqueController {

    @Autowired
    private IBanqueMetier banqueMetier;

    @RequestMapping("/operations")
    public String index()
    {
        return "comptes";
    }
}
```

The html that should be return is this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>MyBanQ</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Test</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

The main application is below. I have tried the solution proposed here [Springboot Whitelabel Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447168/springboot-whitelabel-error-page), but it doesn't work for me.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyBanQApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(MyBanQApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: add  this annotation `@Controller` to your controller

Comment: My bad. Thanks very much. It 's good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the annotation @Controller to your controller class.And your html file name should be "comptes" as you have mention in your index function.