# Repeatedly getting WhiteLabel error page w/ Mapping specification

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to Spring. I am currently following a tutorial to the T and ran into the "Whitelabel error page". I've done my research, checking [Spring boot - Whitelabel Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192140/spring-boot-whitelabel-error-page) and [Spring Boot Remove Whitelabel Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page) with no luck.

I am trying to reach the page by simply using : `http://localhost:8080/hello`

Obviously Spring cannot find the page, but I cannot figure out why that is.

My html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Thymeleaf demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'time on the server is: ' + ${theDate}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cat.otsGrief</groupId>
    <artifactId>GriefReconcile</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GriefReconcile</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Java class:

```
package com.cat.ots.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class DemoController {


    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello(Model theModel) {

        theModel.addAttribute("theDate", new java.util.Date());

        return "helloworld";
    }

}
```

File Structure:

[image]

Any help is appreciated

EDIT:

answer I was looking is found here - [Issue With Spring: There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819277/issue-with-spring-there-was-an-unexpected-error-type-not-found-status-404)

Add component scanning for packages that are not in the same package, or in sub-packages, of the main class.

Comment: Can you show the console error?

Comment: There is no errors in the console. I have actually found the answer I was looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819277/issue-with-spring-there-was-an-unexpected-error-type-not-found-status-404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to configure viewResolver and internalResourceView Resolvers to serve jsp/html files find the below code snippet go through the  [link](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jsp-view-example/)

```
package com.howtodoinjava.app.controller;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```